# Entity Framework - Ensure date is in future

Tags: entity-framework, validation, .net-4.0

We need to validate that the date being stored to the table is a date in the future, is there a way to annotate the property so EF code first can validate and generate the db constraint?

Comment: Can you use Data Annotations? I could provide an example

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add an attribute on your models' property, e.g.

```
[DateInTheFuture]
public DateTime ShippingDate { get; set; }
```

and the attribute is the usual simple validation attribute:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property | AttributeTargets.Field, AllowMultiple = false)]
public class DateInTheFutureAttribute : ValidationAttribute
{
    protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext context)
    {
        var futureDate = value as DateTime?;
        var memberNames = new List<string>() { context.MemberName };

        if (futureDate != null)
        {
            if (futureDate.Value.Date < DateTime.UtcNow.Date)
            {
                return new ValidationResult("This must be a date in the future", memberNames);
            }
        }

        return ValidationResult.Success;
    }
}
```